# Is designing SDR SDRAM controller a difficult task?

Tags: memory, sdram

My book says "Because of many possible modes and options of SDRAM, designing a comprehensiveand robust SDRAM controller is an involved and tedious task". Don't SDR SDRAMs follow some specific standard like all things in the technology world? Why then is does it explicitly say that it is a tedious and involved task?

The book does not name any standard for the SDR SDRAMs. However, I have found that there is something called PC100 that describes it, it is superseded by PC133. However, I have not yet found the documentation that describe them.

Comment: Read the first clause again... If you only need to support a carefully chosen subset of the possible functionality - say, page mode but not the burst modes - you have a much simpler task. PC100/133 basically differed in their data clock rate.

Comment: Yes, there is a standard. Yes, it is tedious. Just because something follows a standard does not mean it is simple. PC100 and PC133 are very old standards. I believe they are published by JEDEC. https://www.jedec.org/

Comment: I searched for PC100 and PC133 in Jedec but did not find anything with that specific title. Basically, I assumed that since there is a standard, there would be an RTL "one fits all" type of solution done by 3rd party that all engineers can use.

Comment: well, it's relative. SDR SDRAM is trivial compared to DDR3. With modern FPGAs, SDRAM frequency can be reached without a lot of efforts. It is complex if you need to develop an universal controller, able to adapt to any SDRAM module with varying latency, supporting all the features of an AMBA AXI interface, reordering writes, delaying refreshes,... Another example is management of banks. You can consider only one bank and close lines every time, or memorize the active line of each bank to optimise performance.

Comment: Datasheets, such as MICRON's, give full and understandable details about how to manage these RAM.

Comment: Thanks TEMLIB, I have seen datasheet of one. However, it seems that all SDRAMs are not identical in how they run. There is a devil in the details.

Comment: DDR3 and DDR4 are also SDRAM

Comment: The question is about SDR SDRAM

Comment: It has been a long time, but I have seen the specifications before. I thought it was JEDEC. Keep looking. You will find it. I think there is RTL IP available. It is just that SDR is almost obsolete nowadays.

Answer (score 3):

A very crude description of SDR SDRAM is [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synchronous_dynamic_random-access_memory#SDR_SDRAM). In fact there is very little difference between the earlier Single-Data-Rate and modern Double-Data-Rate memory in terms of control.

SDRAM is a pain simply because you have to write a controller which has to handle access of the memory in terms of sequencing read and write commands, refreshing the memory, control of the various row/column addressing and pre-charge commands, adding the correct latencies into the control lines, and so on.

This is in contrast to SRAM where in many cases all you do is simply set the address lines and toggle a line to read/write the data.

Give the lower data rates of SDR (100MHz vs. modern DDR3/4 which are 800MHz+), implementing and testing an SDRAM controller is made somewhat simpler in that the physical layer of things is simplified - you can probably get away without the various DLLs and link training that is needed for the ultra-fast speeds of DDR3/4.

However it is still likely to be a tedious task, and one which, given the abundance of perfectly serviceable and in some cases free SDRAM controller IP cores, there is very little to gain by doing it yourself.

Comment: hmm, but in our system we may have different ways to interface with the SDRAM controller? Maybe use something like AXI, Avalon-MM or perhaps something else if it is linked with hard part of our design and is controller by an FSM. Won't that require one to do some sort of rewriting or tampering with any SDRAM controllers code?

Comment: @quantum231 the Altera/Intel DDR controllers use Avalon-MM interfaces. Assuming that's what you are using, Qsys will also automatically add AXI adaption fabric.

Comment: Actually what I am designing will not be used in Qsys. I could use the SDRAM controller from Qsys standalone and create basically an Avalon MM for the controller. That is possible. Though I assume that the performance of that controller will not be very good as it is general purpose.

Comment: By the way, datasheet e g for IS42S86400B says clock frequency 166, 143, 133 MHz. Must memory only be run at one of these? Will controller and the rest of the system also run at that frequency?

Comment: @quantum231 you don't have to run at those, no. The rest of your system can run at some other frequency if you wish so long as you add clock domain crossing logic between the system and the memory controller. The memory controller will always run at the same frequency as the memory.

Comment: I see, does this mean that external memory running at different speed than the system is common and this clock crossing techniques become crucial?

Comment: It can be quite common. Especially in systems where you might have a processor that changes clock frequency with load to save power, or if the max memory frequency doesn't divide nicely into the system clock rate (e.g. 100MHz system, 133MHz RAM).

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not too bad. Most of the datasheets from micron and intersil contain state diagrams that could be used to design a controller around if you wanted to roll your own controller.

I know quartis has a controller for SDRAM to integrate into their QSYS system, they also automatically generate a testbench for modelsim.

I vaguely remember seeing HDL files on microns site for their SDRAM. Opencores has a [16-bit SDRAM controller](https://opencores.org/project,sdram_16bit) that you could look through and use as an example of whatever your implementing.